# Convert JQuery to JS for toggle class

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I am creating a mobile menu and found an example on Codepen, the only problem is that I don't want to load JQuery just for the menu. I'm fairly new to coding and was wondering if there was a way to convert the toggle class function to pure javascript. If you could make a working example that would be ideal. Also if you know of a tool to convert to javascript or something that lists what each function looks like in both so I could covert it myself, that would be good to know.

```js
$(function() {
  
  $(".menu-link").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    
    $(".menu-overlay").toggleClass("open");
    $(".menu").toggleClass("open");

  });
 
});
```

```css
html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: #000;
  font-family: Helvetica Neue, Arial, sans-serif;
  color: #fff;
  overflow: hidden;
}

/* ------------- */
.menu {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  right: 20px;
  height: 46px;
  width: 46px;
}

.menu-link {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1002;
}

.menu-icon {
  position: absolute;
  width: 20px;
  height: 14px;
  margin: auto;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 1px;
}

/* ------------- */
.menu-line {
  background-color: #333;
  height: 2px;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 2px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out;
}
.menu-line-2 {
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
}
.menu-line-3 {
  bottom: 0;
}
.menu.open .menu-line-1 {
  transform: translateY(7px) translateY(-50%) rotate(-45deg);
}
.menu.open .menu-line-2 {
  opacity: 0;
}
.menu.open .menu-line-3 {
  transform: translateY(-7px) translateY(50%) rotate(45deg);
}

/* ------------- */
.menu-circle {
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transform: scale(1);
  z-index: 1000;
  transition: transform 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
.menu:hover .menu-circle {
  transform: scale(1.2);
}
.menu.open .menu-circle {
  transform: scale(60);
}

/* ------------- */
.menu-overlay {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #333;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  text-align: center;
  transition: opacity 0.2s ease-in-out;
  z-index: 1001;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.menu-overlay.open {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}

/* ------------- */
.info {
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
.overlay-info {
  text-align: center;
  color: #111825;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1 class="info">Content</h1>
<div class="menu">
  <span class="menu-circle"></span>
  <a href="#" class="menu-link">
    <span class="menu-icon">
      <span class="menu-line menu-line-1"></span>
      <span class="menu-line menu-line-2"></span>
      <span class="menu-line menu-line-3"></span>
    </span>
  </a>
</div>

<div class="menu-overlay">
  <h1 class="overlay-info">
    Links
  </h1>
    
</div>
```

Comment: so bind an event listener and use classList....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working using onclick="myFunction" and

```js
function myFunction() {
  var menu = document.getElementById("something");
  var overlay = document.getElementById("somethingelse");
  something.classList.toggle("open");
  somethingelse.classList.toggle("open");
}
```